# Open any file from asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio, file-io

How can I open any file, specified by a path, in ASP.NET programatically?

I tried the snippet below but it reads the contents of the file instead of opening the file:

```
string fileName = @"C:\deneme.txt";        
StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fileName);        
while (sr.Peek() != -1)        
{            
    Response.Write(sr.ReadLine() + "<br>");        
}        
sr.Close();
```

I also tried the [`File.Open method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.open.aspx).

Comment: what are you actually trying to do if not read the contents?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Get the file contents as string? Open the file as stream? Get the file contents as byte[]?

Comment: What is the question?  What are you trying to do?  File.Open will open a file - did you have a specific problem with that?  What are you doing with the file once it's open?

Comment: What do you mean by `but it reads the contents of the file instead of opening the file`? How can it read contents without opening the file at all?

Comment: Isn't opening the file means reading the content?? :P

Comment: u mean how to download a file ??

Comment: @grace: no, i need to just open the file, as if i am double clicking to open the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `Response.Redirect` to file if you're just opeining it

or if file is being downloaded you can use the folling code;

```
    public void DownloadFile(string fileName)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = @"application\octet-stream";
        System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(Server.MapPath(FileName));
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
        Response.Flush();
    }
```

Comment: +1. Redirect works not good because it sets not the 200 HTTP status. But method is great!

Comment: @saj: what argument would response.redirect would use?

Comment: Response.Redirect would work for files that can open in browser such as pdf's, word, and excel files. passing in the file path as argument, as VMAtm mentions that would have to be the http path. So won't work if your file is outside the scope of your root virtual directory path

Answer (score 0):

If you want the file to be opened on the client side,Create an [HTTP Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3ff8w4a%28VS.71%29.aspx) and set the appropriate mime type on your response before streaming it out from your handler.

for more information I ask question near to your one before.

[how to open file with its application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3587400/418343)