# Download any kind of file in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using this code on button click from which I can download a file with a specific name.

But I want, when the user has uploaded a file, in his details like any Id proof details file.

Now to verify the user admin want to see the his Id proof details.
So he will download the file which user had uploaded and that is saved in database.

So the file can be in any type or extension.

```
private void Button1_click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string filename="C:\myuploads\invoice.pdf";
    Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;" + filename +);
    Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(filename));
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Are you positive you want an upload function that allows any file, also executable files (.exe, .msi ...)? That should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733136/open-any-file-from-asp-net

Comment: While https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783921/which-mime-type-to-use-for-a-binary-file-thats-specific-to-my-program isn't exactly a duplicate its answer does talk about `application/octet-stream` which is a generic content type you can use for any file you want.

Comment: What exactly are you asking here? It's really unclear. What part of downloading files, etc. don't you understand?

Comment: I want to download a file which user has uploaded on clicking download button in gridview and file can be of any type.

Comment: @MohiniGalhotra and the problem is what? What doesn't work? You already have the upload control, you posted the code that will send the file to the browser. What is the question? What is the problem?

Comment: @MohiniGalhotra please don't repeat the question text in the comment. Or "but it doesn't work". It won't help at all. Actually explaining what the problem is and what you want to *ask*, will help. You already posted download code, you already use a FileUpload control. Why do you need to post a question to SO then?

Comment: @MohiniGalhotra is there something wrong with your code or do you want to ask how to populate the gridview? How to generate the button? How to find the current grid row? How to connect to the database?

Comment: @MohiniGalhotra first you should restrict the file types as it will create security issues later on.

Comment: @ Nirzar.. Thanks for your response but I want make dynamic filepath.. It want to just specify the folder in which the file is located. But I want file name should be dynamic and it should pick file of that particular client Id from gridview on which row has been clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for answering my questions. My LinkButton to downloading the file from database on particular user Id worked Successfully.

Actually My Download Link was in update panel so It needs the "Trigger" for this.. And My Link was in GridView So I had Passed the Link Button Id in Trigger.

**Whenever we use GridView in Update Panel and There is a LinkButton to Download the File from database on particular user Id. We Should Pass **GridView Id** not the LinkButton Id in Template Field.**

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:GridView ID="grd_UserList" runat="server" CssClass="table"
      DataKeyNames="Uid" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="false">
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Task Name">
          <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton Id="LinkDownload" runat="Server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Attachment") %>' >
          </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>

      </asp:GridView>
     </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="grd_UserList" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you're after.

```
private void DownloadFile(string file)
{
    var fi = new FileInfo(file);
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+ fi.Name);
    Response.WriteFile(file);
    Response.End();
}
```

So you just call it like this:

```
string myfile = @"c:\path\To\Files\myFile.pdf"; //this wouldn't be a static string in your code
DownloadFile(myfile);
```

Comment: Yate... Thanks for help. As you have taken a variable

string myfile = @"c:\path\To\Files\myFile.pdf"; 
DownloadFile(myfile);

This will pick up the file with the name of myfile.pdf file name. But In my case there can be any file with any type of extension.

Comment: Yes and that code will download any file type you ask, so set the `myfile` to be whatever you need and you are sorted.  It can be `string myfile = @"c:\path\To\Files\myFile.xyz"` and it'll download it.

Comment: This solution works great but I have not been able to get it to work with wav files. Mp3 is working well.

Answer (score 0):

When the user uploads the file, you should be able to use the `ContentType` property of the posted file. This is assuming you used a file upload control like:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="uploadFile" runat="server" />
```

When the file is uploaded, get the content type using

```
string fileType = uploadFile.PostedFile.ContentType
```

Save that value in your DB, and use it as the value of `Reponse.ContentType` in your existing code, when you download it later.

Comment: Yes, I am using File Upload Control there and along with this control I also have download link button to download that file which have been uploaded..

Comment: ok well I think this shows you how you can capture the file's content type and use it later when you offer the file for downloading, so that the file is downloaded properly. Does that answer your question, or did you mean something else?

Comment: @MohiniGalhotra and the problem is *what*? You already have the upload control, you posted the code that will send the file to the browser. What is the question? What is the **problem**?

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos.. I am to download the file. The code is not giving the error but also not downloading the file of user.

Comment: @MohiniGalhotra that is not a problem description. Did you try debugging? *Can* your code read an arbitrary file outside the web site's folder? I doubt it. Most likely, there is a permission exception that gets hidden with a `catch{}` or something similar

Comment: Permission is not a problem because I have checked by downloading the image from browser. My code is not downloading the file which is saved in database of particular user.

Comment: @MohiniGalhotra `MapPath` is used to convert a relative path to an absolute path relative to the *web site's folder*. You can't use it or need it to read an absolute path. Permissions *are* most definitelly a problem, but the code is probably looking for the wrong path. By default your web app *can't* read anything outside the site's root folder

Comment: @MohiniGalhotra judging by what you've said, you _should_ be getting an exception stating the file cannot be found, or similar. You talk about a database, but your code sample hard-codes the filename. Are we to understand that the code you posted above is not your real code? If so please paste the real code, and please check for any exceptions by running your code in debug mode, and breaking on exceptions. We can't fix something we can't see. Also, in the question you never mentioned that the file won't download - instead you asked about the file type, which led to my answer. Please be clearer

Comment: Yes here have mentioned the file path hard coded but I only want to give the folder name filename should be dynamic because It need to find the file of particular client Id on which user detail I have clicked.

Comment: ok well then you need to add the code to do that, if you haven't already. We can't help with that because we know nothing about the database or the table structure. It's up to you to change it. And it's not clear if this is related to the inability to download the file or not. Have you done what we suggested and checked properly for exceptions or other errors? Have  you verified that this download code is even being executed? Have you tried removing MapPath as suggested? It seems like you have not done the basic debugging tasks necessary for solving any kind of problem like this.

Comment: I have done the debugging task as suggested and in filename, It is showing the filepath and name of file in variable but not downloading the file.

Comment: "not downloading" isn't really a good description. There must be an error occurring. Perhaps you have suppressed exceptions somehow? Does your app have any logs you can check? Even the standard windows application event log might contain some info. But I notice you are sending the whole file path as the download filename. This is unlikely to work. The header also may not be constructed properly. Try `Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\" + filename + "\"");` and also just use "invoice.pdf" (in your example) as the filename for this header, not the whole path.

Comment: (You can do that by splitting the original path string using \ as the separator, and taking the last returned part of the array, which should be the filename only)