# How to assign the link path out of the application in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

How to assign the link path out of the application in asp.net?

Normally the application will be stored in

> C:\Documents and Settings\MyName\My Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\

I only able to let the user to access the file within the Projects.

in web browser, it will be displayed as http://localhost:4783/Images/image.bmp

my question is how to enable the user to access the item out of the application?
for example:

> C:\Documents and Settings\ITEMS\

if i just assign the absolute path which is

```
<a href="C:\Documents and Settings\ITEMS\image.bmp>Click</a>
```

The result will be `http://localhost:1888/C:/Documents and Settings/ITEMS/image.bmp`
and it is not correct.

Comment: This is really a web server setup issue, where you need to set up a virtual directory on whatever web server you are using pointing to your ITEMS directory.  Then you can point your hrefs to the new virtual directory and not a physical directory.

Comment: Try use protocol `file://`, for example 'file:///c:/Documents and Settings/ITEMS/image.bmp'

Comment: @fliptheweb the `file://` protocol is local

Comment: @DEN: Here's a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763173.aspx) on how to setup virtual directories in IIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is that you use a local path, the user cant access that because it is not part of 
your webserver virtual directory.

The File URI Sheme should be

```
file:///c:/Documents and Settings/ITEMS....
```

But, again, this only works on your machine if the users dont have direct access
from their machines to this path.

more informations about the [File URI Sheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)

But you should read [Configuring IIS Web Sites and Virtual Directories](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-iis.html)

Comment: it is only working in internet explorer but google chrome fail to open it. any alternative?

Comment: this is a security restriction, i think, because. Please check out how to configure your webserver to prevent links like that.

Answer (score 0):

Users don't have a permission to access the resources outside the virtual folder. You must have to add/copy the `resources` (images or other files) under `virtual` folder.

Answer (score 0):

> If you want the file to be opened on the client side, your best bet is
>   to create and HTTP Handler

For more information, you can look to this question:

[How to open file with its application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3587400/418343)